# Index out of range in subscript when conforming to RandomAccessCollection in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I created a class and confirming it to `ObservableObject` as well as `RandomAccessCollection` think of this class as a custom implementation of Array but I don't need it to be a struct. I need it to be a class.

I try to add an item to the class's content by calling a custom function named `append` and that works fine but when I come to delete, it for some reason crashes at `subscript` I tried to trace it and it seems like everytime I delete it loops through everything includes the deleted item and then it crashes. So I am not really sure what is going on. Here is a piece of code with reproducable code (just copy and paste it)

If I change my code to struct it works 100% fine but I need it as a class.

**Test.swift**

```
import Foundation

public class Test<Element : Hashable>: ObservableObject{
    @Published fileprivate var contents:[Element] = []
    
    public var count:Int {
        return self.contents.count
    }
    
    init() {
        
    }
}

public extension Test {
    func append(_ newElement: Element) {
        self.contents.append(newElement)
    }
    
    func remove(_ at: Int) {
        self.contents.remove(at: at)
    }
}

extension Test : Collection, RandomAccessCollection {
    public typealias Index = Int
    public typealias Indices = CountableRange<Int>
    
    public var startIndex: Int {
        return self.contents.startIndex
    }
    
    public var endIndex: Int {
        return self.contents.endIndex
    }
    
    public subscript(position: Int) -> Element {
        get {
            return self.contents[position] // Crash occurs here after trying to remove
        }
    }
    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return self.contents.index(after: i)
    }
    
    public func index(before i: Int) -> Int {
        return self.contents.index(before: i)
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var test: Test<String> = Test<String>()
    @State var input: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("New Item", text: self.$input)
                
                Button("Add", action: {
                    if(!self.input.isEmpty) {
                        self.test.append(self.input)
                    }
                })
            }
            
            Button("Remove", action: {
                self.test.remove(0)
            }).disabled(self.test.count <= 0)
            
            List {
                ForEach(self.test, id:\.self) { n in
                    Text(n)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach` does not see changes in data, because `self.test` is a reference.

Here is possible workaround (and still have Test's `contents` private). Tested with Xcode 11.7 / iOS 13.7

```
    List {
        ForEach(Array(self.test), id:\.self) { n in
            Text(n)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can see the list changing with adding your code and also without; however, the problem I still get `Index out of range` when I try to remove even after making the changes you proposed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does indeed solve it but I understand it is a workaround. I also understand that `ForEach` is not seeing the changes but what I  can't wrap my head around is why is it able to see the changes when I do an `add` but not `remove`? Also Do you think there is no way to do this without the hack at this point in time? or is what I am asking for impossible at the moment with classes? Because the above code works 100% fine with `struct` but I understand Structs are value type. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're exceeding your array bounds, you could make the return value for your collection optional or you could give a default value in the init that you can return when the array is empty.

```
@ObservedObject var test: Test<String> = Test<String>(emptyValue: "")

public class Test<Element : Hashable>: ObservableObject{
    private let empty: Element
    @Published fileprivate var contents:[Element] = []

    public var count:Int {
        return self.contents.count
    }
    init(emptyValue: Element) {
        empty = emptyValue
    }
}

extension Test {
    func append(_ newElement: Element) {
        self.contents.append(newElement)
    }

    func remove(_ at: Int) {
        self.contents.remove(at: at)
    }
}

extension Test : Collection, RandomAccessCollection {
    public typealias Index = Int
    public typealias Indices = CountableRange<Int>

    public var startIndex: Int {
        return self.contents.startIndex
    }

    public var endIndex: Int {
        return self.contents.endIndex
    }

    public subscript(position: Int) -> Element {
        get {
            position < self.contents.count ? self.contents[position] : empty
        }
    }
    public func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return self.contents.index(after: i)
    }

    public func index(before i: Int) -> Int {
        return self.contents.index(before: i)
    }
}
```